# Passing arguments to sql template from airflow operator

Tags: python, airflow

If I am using a BigQueryOperator with a SQL Template, how could I pass an argument to the SQL?

**File**: .sql/query.sql

```
SELECT * FROM `dataset.{{ task_instance.variable_for_execution }}
```

**File**: dag.py

```
BigQueryOperator(
    task_id='compare_tables',
    sql='./sql/query.sql',
    use_legacy_sql=False,
    dag=dag,
)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can pass an argument in `params` parameter which can be used in the templated field as follows:

```
BigQueryOperator(
    task_id='',
    sql='SELECT * FROM `dataset.{{ params.param1 }}',
    params={
        'param1': 'value1',
        'param2': 'value2'
    },
    use_legacy_sql=False,
    dag=dag
)
```

OR you can have the SQL separate in file:

**File**: ./sql/query.sql

```
SELECT * FROM `dataset.{{ params.param1 }}
```

`params` parameter's input should be a dictionary. In general, any operator in Airflow can be passed this `params` parameter.